# Set hivevar to value of conditional expression

Tags: hive, hiveql

Is it possible to set a hivevar in an hql script like so?

```
set hivevar:tab=(CASE ${hiveconf:res} WHEN 'A' THEN 'DAILY' WHEN 'B' THEN '' END);
```

And then, immediately use it (i.e not in SELECT query) to set another var on the next line?

```
set hivevar:oct=(IF(${hivevar:tab} = '', true, false));
```

Being called like: `hive -hiveconf res=A -f hivefile.hql`
I'm attempting to translate a stored proc that has variable setting logic like above before bulk workload. I'm currently making the case to my team to use a different approach (not straight HQL), but I'd like to have an answer if they press for this.